# What is the name of the developer package or Python runtime package in SuSE LES 11 SP1?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

_**I had problem with installing the mod_wsgi.I have found the solution as below (I am quite sure this is the solution to my problem) in its website. However, I don't know the name of the developer package or Python runtime package in SuSE LES 11 SP1. Can any one tell me? Thank you_**.

In order to compile mod_wsgi from source code you must have installed the full Python distribution, including header files. On a Linux distribution where binary Python packages are split into a runtime package and a developer package, the developer package is often not installed by default. This means that you will be missing the header files required to compile mod_wsgi from source code. An example of the error messages you will see if the developer package is not installed are:

```
mod_wsgi.c:113:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:114:21: error: compile.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:115:18: error: node.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:116:20: error: osdefs.h: No such file or directory
mod_wsgi.c:119:2: error: #error Sorry, mod_wsgi requires at least Python 2.3.0.
mod_wsgi.c:123:2: error: #error Sorry, mod_wsgi requires that Python supporting thread.
```

To remedy the problem, **install the developer package for Python corresponding to the Python runtime package you have installed. What the name of the developer package is can vary from one Linux distribution to another. Normally it has the same name as the Python runtime package with '-dev' appended to the package name. You will need to lookup up list of available packages in your packaging system to determine actual name of package to install**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

http://software.opensuse.org/search?q=%22python-dev%22&baseproject=openSUSE%3A11.4&lang=en

Looks like it might be called 'python-devel'.